# 3D printed engraving/embossing mesh using a bitmap

Tags: displacement

The problem:
Searching for a way to create engravings/coins/etc in Blender.
I need it to actually displace the mesh, not just appear to, so it can be 3d printed.

I've tried:

- Subdividing a plane and applying a displacement works but looks awful and is a very heavy mesh.
- Uploaded the image to a "lithophane" maker and downloaded the result. Looks awful and makes a very heavy mesh.
- Boolean modifier randomly generates unprintable or garbage meshes

Any suggestions?

Comment: The subdivision and Displacement thing sounds like the standard, however you may be subdividing too much. I don’t know what to tell you except to do that and then use limited dissolve to try to knock down on extra vertices.

Comment: I tried using optimize on the mesh after displacement. It removed a lot of the weight but it was still ugly. I assume unless the mesh has three ngons per pixel you won't get a decent conversion. I may try that next. Thanks